# Going into ADB sideload isn't changing device status

Tags: adb, recovery, sideloading, lineageos

I'm trying to sideload a new ROM onto my device, but for some reason it's not working.

I rebooted my device into recovery(19.1 lineageOS recovery), enabled ADB, then went Apply Update->Apply from ADB. This is supposed to set the device into sideload mode. However, when I go to ADB(platform-rools_r35.0.0) and type in `./adb devices` my device is still showing up with status "unauthorized" instead of "sideload". I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: adb sideload is a special adb mode. I don't know if it supports authorization at all as it is only used for uploading signed firmware updates. So `adb shell` or pull/push will not work in sideload mode.